# Can't connect Laravel to RabbitMQ Docker

Tags: php, docker, rabbitmq, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I've set up the Laravel server and RabbitMQ in Docker containers using Laravel Sail. When I try to run `sail artisan queue:work` I get these errors for these hosts:

- rabbit: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for rabbit failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
- localhost: Cannot assign requested address
- 192.168.16.2 (IP from `docker inspect rabbitmq` results): Connection refused
- 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

I can access the management console on `http://127.0.0.1:15672/` and can log in using guest@guest as is set in `.env` and `config/queue.php` files.

I'm using the `vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` package.

`Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -Port 5672` produces:

```
ComputerName     : 127.0.0.1
RemoteAddress    : 127.0.0.1
RemotePort       : 5672
InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress    : 127.0.0.1
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

The container was set up with these lines in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
rabbitmq:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
        - '5672:5672'
        - '15672:15672'
```

Comment: could you post your whole compose file?

Comment: @C1sc0 sure, here's the whole file https://pastebin.com/cSPpk1nz

Comment: Try to put the rabbitmq container too in the depends_on: part of your sail container also use rabbitmq instead of rabbit in your config (RABBITMQ_HOST)

Comment: @C1sc0 Thanks for looking into it! I did as you instructed - it did not help.

Comment: Also your rabbitmq container is not in the sail network

Comment: @C1sc0 that was it! Thanks, man! Appreciate it!